# How do I set Indent property on XmlWriter for specific element node

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

Sorry if title is confusing, here is what I want to achieve. I have a XmlWriter object that is being created and passed to a method

```
public static void foo(XmlWriter xw)
{
   xw.WriteStartElement("root");
}
```

At this point XmlWriter was instantiated, and Xml declaration was already written. Now, afer the root element is written, I need to set Indent property on XmlWriter to true ( it was set to false when XmlWriter was created ). Something like this

```
public static void foo(XmlWriter xw)
{
   xw.WriteStartElement("root");
   // xw.Settings.Indent = true; - I know this won't work
   // continue writing elements...
}
```

Can't find a way how to set Indent at that point. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use XmlTextWriter. You can then set the Indentation property to the number of spaces you want to indent. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.indentation.aspx

To use the Indent property, you can't have mixed content
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent.aspx

"The elements are indented as long as the element does not contain mixed content. Once the WriteString or WriteWhitespace method is called to write out a mixed element content, the XmlWriter stops indenting. The indenting resumes once the mixed content element is closed."

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, thou I would rather stick to XmlWriter, cuz changing it to XmlTextWriter would require me to change this whole module. All the components rely on XmlWriter, so I can't make easy changes. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I did some more researching. You can't change the Settings property once the XmlWriter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.settings.aspx

Comment: It seems like you'll need to refactor the module if you want to indent or update where the XmlWriter is created and pass in XmlWriterSettings

Comment: Well, yes after spending hours on this, I decided to not change Xml creation process itself, but make changes in resulting XML file because in my case I was needing to remove indent between Xml declaration and root node. But I'm going to mark your reply as an answer, because it's the only reply and contains some useful informataion.